# Trouble Applying Function to Each Cell in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a single column ('`publish_time`') of type datetime.  I want to just get the times, so I tried something like this:

```
df.applymap(datetime.time)
```

Unfortunately, I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: ('an integer is required', u'occurred at index publish_time')
```

I'm a little lost here because I'm applying a `datetime` function to a bunch of `datetime` objects, so I don't know why Python expects an integer.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `dt` accessor, you can get the time component in a vectorized way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'publish_time': ['20170606 12:04', '20170606 17:02']})

df
Out: 
     publish_time
0  20170606 12:04
1  20170606 17:02

df['publish_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publish_time'])

df['publish_time'].dt.time
Out: 
0    12:04:00
1    17:02:00
Name: publish_time, dtype: object
```